# Base58 returns incorrect value in elixir

Tags: elixir, bitcoin, base58

I'm trying to encode hex to base58. It works with js library `base-x`

with hex = `1777c7ba65e23151ec09125011dd25c28998c70230e7b89ca6`

**Expected**

base58 = `AShDKgLSuCjGZr8Fs5SRLSYvmcSV7S4zwX`

**Got**

base58 = `cAvfov2bvPACeGktuSEtz6G526UBfCwpia1354fp5bYJwP2rhhnxqYkRcwRoDrmgqZaG`

```
defmodule Base58 do
  @alphabet '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

  def encode(data, hash \\ "")

  def encode(data, hash) when is_binary(data) do
    encode_zeros(data) <> encode(:binary.decode_unsigned(data), hash)
  end

  def encode(0, hash), do: hash

  def encode(data, hash) do
    character = <<Enum.at(@alphabet, rem(data, 58))>>
    encode(div(data, 58), character <> hash)
  end

  defp encode_zeros(data) do
    <<Enum.at(@alphabet, 0)>>
    |> String.duplicate(leading_zeros(data))
  end

  defp leading_zeros(data) do
    :binary.bin_to_list(data)
    |> Enum.find_index(&(&1 != 0))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that the input is supposed to be the chunk of binary data represented by those hexadecimal digits, but you passed the string containing the hexadecimal digits to `Base58.encode` instead.  You get the expected result if you pass the input as an integer (using the `0x` prefix to mark it as a hexadecimal literal integer):

```
iex(2)> Base58.encode("1777c7ba65e23151ec09125011dd25c28998c70230e7b89ca6")
"cAvfov2bvPACeGktuSEtz6G526UBfCwpia1354fp5bYJwP2rhhnxqYkRcvTMFJ2ouddX"
iex(3)> Base58.encode(0x1777c7ba65e23151ec09125011dd25c28998c70230e7b89ca6)
"AShDKgLSuCjGZr8Fs5SRLSYvmcSV7S4zwX"
```

If you already have this data in a string, you can use [`Integer.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2) to convert it to an integer:

```
iex(5)> with {integer, _} <- Integer.parse("1777c7ba65e23151ec09125011dd25c28998c70230e7b89ca6", 16) do
...(5)>   Base58.encode(integer)
...(5)> end
"AShDKgLSuCjGZr8Fs5SRLSYvmcSV7S4zwX"
```

Comment: I see i needed to send binary not hex string i used this `"1777c7ba65e23151ec09125011dd25c28998c70230e7b89ca6" |> Base.decode16!(case: :mixed) |> Base58.encode()` thanks